# If the integral of $|f_n|$ converges to zero, so does the integral of $f_ng$ for integrable $g$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let's assume that the $f_n$ are integrable and all bounded with the same bound. also, that $\int|f_n|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

(a) Prove under these assumptions that $\int f_ng\to0$ for any $g\in C_{cpt}^0$. Here, $C_{cpt}^0$ is a compact, continuous function.

(b)Prove the same for any integrable g.

I know that $\int |f_n|\to 0$ does NOT imply $f_n(x)\to 0$ almost everywhere. However, being new to analysis and trying to learn this as extra knowledge is making the "fun" of learning very frustrating at this point and time.

Comment: Note that $\int |f_n g| \le \int |f_n| \,\|g\|_{\infty} = \|g\|_{\infty} \int |f_n|$.

Comment: For (b), note that the compactly supported continuous functions are dense in $L^1$.

Comment: What does the $0$ on $C_{cpt}^0$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, since $g$ is of compact support, it is bounded. Hence $\|g\|_{\infty} < \infty$, so

$$\int |f_ng| = \int |f_n| |g| \le \int |f_n| \|g\|_{\infty} = \|g\|_{\infty} \int |f_n| \to 0$$

For the second, note that: $\overline{C^{0}_{cpt}} = L^1$ (wrt $\|\cdot \|_1$), so for $g \in L^1$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a continuous $g_{\epsilon}$ of compact support such that $\|g-g_{\epsilon}\|_1 < \epsilon$. So:

$$\int |f_ng| = \int |f_n (g-g_{\epsilon}) + f_ng_{\epsilon}| \le \int |f_n||g-g_{\epsilon}| + \int|f_n g_{\epsilon}|$$

By $1)$, the rightmost integral converges to $0$. And I suppose that by "all $f_n$ are bounded with some bound" you mean that for some $M > 0$, $\|f_n\|_{\infty} \le M$ for all $n$. Therefore for large $n$,

$$\int |f_n g| < M \epsilon + \epsilon$$

Now you just need to make the argument more rigorous.

Comment: it looks as though you have answered the question? Why (how) would I need to make this more rigorous? I'm not super certain what "more rigorous" even means. Forgive me